# MonoTouch: Help converting a couple lines of Objective C to C#

Tags: xamarin.ios

Since coming from a pure C# background I am having a little bit of trouble with some of the Objective C syntax.  I am playing around with the Audio Queue and I am trying to set the InputAudioQueue property EnableLevelMetering and get the CurrentLevelMeterDB property.  I found a couple examples in Objective C.

Setting the property:

```
UInt32 enabledLevelMeter = true;
AudioQueueSetProperty(queue,kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering,&enabledLevelMeter,sizeof(UInt32));
```

Getting the value:

```
AudioQueueLevelMeterState levelMeter;
UInt32 levelMeterSize = sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState);
AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB,&levelMeter,&levelMeterSize);

Float32 peakDB = levelMeter.mPeakPower;
Float32 averageDB = levelMeter.mAveragePower;
```

The [API reference](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioQueue.GetProperty%28MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioQueueProperty%2cSystem.Int32%40%29) for AudioQueue is very minimal. I am not sure what to use for the following values in C#.

```
public bool SetProperty (AudioQueueProperty property, int dataSize, IntPtr propertyData)
public IntPtr GetProperty (AudioQueueProperty property, out int size)
```

Could somebody help a me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your AudioQueue created (input or output), you can call:

```
int enabled = queue.GetProperty<int> (AudioQueueProperty.EnableLevelMetering);
```

Setting it is a little bit more annoying, you have to use:

```
queue.SetProperty (AudioQueueProperty.EnableLevelMetering, 4, (IntPtr) &enabled);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Miguel, you rule!

Comment: On the next version of MonoTouch EnableLevelMetering is a bool property on the AudioQueue